# Error on django-admin startproject

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I a trying to create a django project by using "django-admin startproject sitedemo" but the following error came

```
shivam@shivam-HP-15-Notebook-PC:~$ django-admin startproject sitedemo
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in <module>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 933, in subscribe
    callback(dist)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3032, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2576, in activate
    for pkg in self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2566, in _get_metadata
    for line in self.get_metadata_lines(name):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1589, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1581, in get_metadata
    return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help1692, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/protobuf-3.0.0b3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/namespace_packages.txt'
```

please help me how to resolve these errors and create a project in django

Comment: I really don't get how `http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help1692` comes to play in your traceback o.O

Comment: try to use Python 3

Answer (score 0):

Okk ! I think you have not created any virtual enviornment first.
So please first create the enviornment for this project like

```
virtualenv enviornment_name
cd enviornment_name
source bin/activate
cd  ..
django-admin.py startproject sitedemo
```

Comment: Please don't. Learn to use virtualenv.

Comment: then plz try using sudo...like sudo django-admin.py startproject sitedemo